# Spring data mongodb No mapping metadata found for java.util.Date result of aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have been getting a No mapping `metadata` found for `java.util.Date exception` as a result of an `aggregation` pipeline, here is the code:

**Model:**

```
public class Model {
    // ...
    private List<DateValue> dateValues = new ArrayList<>();
    // setter and getters
}

public class DateValue {
    private Date date;
    private BigDecimal value;
    // setter and getters
}
```

i then have a custom repository implementation that looks like this:

**ModelRepositoryImpl:**

```
public class ModelRepositoryImpl implements ModelRepositoryCustom {
   // ...
    @Override
    public Date findMaxDate() {
        final Direction direction = Direction.DESC;

        final AggregationResults<Date> result = operations.aggregate( newAggregation( Model.class,
                match( where( "dateValues" ).elemMatch( new Criteria().exists( true ) ) ),
                sort( new Sort( direction, "dateValues.date" ) ),
                limit( 1 ),
                project().and( "dateValues.date" ).as( "date" ),
                unwind( "date" ),
                sort( new Sort( direction, "date" ) ),
                limit( 1 ) )
                , Date.class );

        return result.getUniqueMappedResult();
    }

}
```

this is the stacktrace: https://pastebin.ca/3947962

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

So I tried your example at home and got the same problem. I was sure there was an elegant way just couldn't test it earlier today. The thing is MongoDB returns Documents. Even if you just return the field `date`, it is still returned in that form:

```
{
    "date" : ISODate("2017-12-14T19:00:00.000Z")
}
```

So all you have to do is create a new class that only contains a field Date. Here is my updated solution.

Create a class:

```
public class DateResult {
    private Date date;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

And then change your `findMaxDate()` to this:

```
public Date findMaxDate() {
    final Direction direction = Direction.DESC;

    final AggregationResults <DateResult> result = operations.aggregate(newAggregation(Model.class,
        match(where("dateValues").elemMatch(new Criteria().exists(true))),
        sort(new Sort(direction, "dateValues.date")), limit(1), project().and("dateValues.date").as("date"),
        unwind("date"), sort(new Sort(direction, "date")), limit(1)), DateResult.class);

    return result.getUniqueMappedResult().getDate();
}
```

---

Try adding `@Document` to your POJO class

Check out the official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage)

> To take full advantage of the object mapping functionality inside the
>   Spring Data/MongoDB support, you should annotate your mapped objects
>   with the @Document annotation.

OR

What also helped for me in certain use cases was to use `DBObject.class` as result and then map them myself.

```
final AggregationResults<DBObject> result = operations.aggregate( newAggregation( 
                match( where( "dateValues" ).elemMatch( new Criteria().exists( true ) ) ),
                sort( new Sort( direction, "dateValues.date" ) ),
                limit( 1 ),
                project().and( "dateValues.date" ).as( "date" ),
                unwind( "date" ),
                sort( new Sort( direction, "date" ) ),
                limit( 1 ) )
                , DBObject.class );

List<DBObject> dbObjectResults = result.getMappedResults();
```

or in your case since you set the limit to 1 you can also use:

```
DBObject dbObjectResult = result.getUniqueMappedResult();
```

Then you could get your values out of your BDObject

```
Date dateFromField = mapToDate(dbObjectResult .get("date")); // if your field is called "date"

private static Date mapToDate(Object document) {
        if (document == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (document.getClass()
                    .equals(Date.class)) {
            return (Date) document;
        }
        if (document.getClass()
                    .equals(DateTime.class)) {
            return new DateTime(document).toDate();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: i have already tried that, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Check out the second part, maybe using DBObject works for you. But I'm not sure why the first solution doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks that works! im going to wait for a while before accepting, because it feels like there should be a way to make it work automatically.

Comment: @davidebubz no problem mate, I feel you.

Comment: for future reference for the people that may end up using this solution, i found out that dbObjectResult can be null, therefore a check is needed before use.

Comment: @davidebubz I found a better solution, check it out!